# Bootstrap:How to overlap two forms on an image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to overlay two forms on an image on my webpage. But the result is the forms are beneath the image in browser window. help me 
my code segment is

```
<head>
        <title>MyHealth template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     media="screen">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <div class="row pos-rel">
            <img src="images/land.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="image">
            <!--form1-->
            <div class="col-xs-4 form-cl1">
                <form class="form form-cl2" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 form-gp">
                        <label for="check"><h3>Health CheckUp for</h3></label><br>
                        <select id="check" class="form-control input-lg"></select><br>
                            <label for="location"><h4>My Location</h4></label>
                        <select id="location" class="form-control input-lg"></select>   <br>
                        <select id="location" class="form-control input-lg"    style="width:45%;display:inline;"></select>
                        <select id="location" class="form-control input-lg"     style="width:45%;display:inline;float:right;"></select>
                        <label><h4>Preffered cost range</h4></label><br>
                        <img src="images/cost range.png" width="100%"><br><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <label for="from">From</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"     id="from">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <label for="from">To</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block"     style=""><h4><b>Suggest me Health Check Packages</b></h4></button><br>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css is

```
.pos-rel
{
    position:relative;
}
#image
{
    z-index:0;
    width:100%;
    height:858px;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
 .sec-col1
{
    z-index:3;
    font-family:'futura std medium';
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:90px;
}
.list1
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    z-index:2;
    color:black;
}
.form-cl1
{
    float:right;
    margin-top:110px;
    margin-right:20px;
    z-index:7;
    font-family:'futura std light';
    color:#fff;
    display:inline;
}
.form-cl2
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:7;
    background:url(images/rectangle1.png);
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
}
.form-gp
{
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. It's impossible to help without it

Comment: Put image `position: absolute; z-index: 5`, forms: `position: relative; z-index: 6`

Comment: @Justin put your two forms inside a `div` and use the image as `background-image` of that div.

Comment: @MaryMelody but with user provided HTML structure, it's only possible solution :D

Comment: @Justin Please format your code by edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two options:
1) Set image `position: absolute;` and form will overlap that image.
2) Set image as `background: url()`.

Either way you have to specify wrapper dimensions. Using [2] will cut edges of image if container is smaller. Using [1] will show full image.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0dcn3hj/)